# NServiceBus: bus.Defer() and bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers()

Tags: nservicebus

This is a two part question, sorry.

Part 1
When using bus.Defer() with NServiceBus, where are the "deferred" messages stored? Back into the queue of the handler that deferred them (similar to bus.SendLocal()), or does it use RavenDB to store the deferred message?

Part 2
When using bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers(), what happens to the message? Is the message dropped on the floor, moved to the audit queue, etc...

???

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using bus.Defer() with NServiceBus, where are the "deferred" messages stored?

The deferred messages are stored in the configured persistence you have picked, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/persistence/ for more information.

> When using bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers(), what happens to the message?

Assuming you are calling `bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers()` from within an handler, the message is still being processed exactly the same way as before, the only difference is that NServiceBus won't execute any more handlers for that message, so in essence the message is processed up till this point. If auditing is ON, the message will be audited.

---

If you have any further questions feel free to ask us in our forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware